# Add Function to entity in LINQ

Tags: linq, vb.net-2010

Let say I have an entity `customer` using northwind database.

If I created a function `GetCustomerByID` under `partial class customer`. I can execute this function by using `Linq` query such as

```
Dim q = From t in db.Customers where t.GetCustomerByID(my_parameter) Select T
```

If I created the function under `partial class dx_northwindDataContext`. I can execute this function by using :

```
Dim result = db.GetCustomerByID(my_parameter)
```

Since I am creating Data Access Layer for my database, and for not exposing all my function to all my entity to the `db` variable. I was looking for a way of calling my functions like :

```
Dim result = db.Customers.GetCustomerByID(my_parameter)
```

Is there away to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can create [an extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx) for `db.Customers` like:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

    Module IQueryableExtensions

        <Extension()> 
        Public Function GetCustomerByID(ByVal source As IQueryable(Of Customer), ByVal id As Int32) As IQueryable(Of Customer)
            return source.Where(Function(f)f.Id == id)
        End Sub

    End Module
```